# Spring declarative transactions beginning after service methods return

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I've been teaching myself Spring 3.0 by implementing a JavaEE Web-app using:

- **Tomcat** 7
- **Spring** 3.0, Security 3.1
- **JPA**: EclipseLink 2.3.1
- **MySQL** 5.5, Connector/J 5.1

---

**My problem** is:

- I've set up declarative transaction management on my *service layer* using Spring AOP.
- (I also have a Spring AOP logging interceptor, declared in the same place.)
- **Creating** new entities isn't a problem.
- **Updating** existing entities is!
- <strike>According to the log, the **service method** returns before the **transaction** begins!</strike>

  ```
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Using transaction object [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject@335f5e3a]>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Creating new transaction with name [org.snowjak.livesavegive.data.service.TagService.rename]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Opened new EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@3a234c2f] for JPA transaction>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [SimpleConnectionHandle: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@49116f61]>
  [myproject.data.service.MyEntityService] - <Beginning method: rename>
  [myproject.data.dao.MyEntityDao] - <Beginning method: get>
  [myproject.data.dao.MyEntityDao] - <After method: get>
  [myproject.data.dao.AbstractDao] - <Beginning method: update>
  [myproject.data.dao.AbstractDao] - <After method: update>
  [myproject.data.service.MyEntityService] - <After method: rename>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Triggering beforeCommit synchronization>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction commit>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@3a234c2f]>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Triggering afterCommit synchronization>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Triggering afterCompletion synchronization>
  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - <Closing JPA EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@3a234c2f] after transaction>
  ```
- This inability-to-update disappears if I make my DAOs transactional, not my service-layer.
- But The Authorities say that that's Bad Style.

Can anyone offer any pointers/tips/tricks/secrets of the guild?

#### Edit:

I've turned on `DEBUG` detail for org.springframework in my logger; and see that, from what I can tell, transactions are being handled correctly after all -- i.e., being begun before and ended after the service method in question.

I still have a problem updating, viz. my updates don't appear in the PU nor the DB; now why would that be? ...

#### Edit:

I've also peeked into the MySQL general-log while I made my update attempt. JPA, it seems, simply isn't issuing `UPDATE`s to the database!

==================================================================================

#### Entities:

- Under `myproject.data.entity`. Nothing special. Generic JPA.

  ```
  @Entity
  public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      int id;

      @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
      String name;

      ...
  }
  ```

---

#### DAOs:

**Interfaces under `myproject.data.dao`.**

- `interface AbstractDao`

  ```
  @Repository
  interface AbstractDao<T,K> extends Serializable {
      public T get(K key);
      public Collection<T> getAll();

      public T save(T entity);
      public T update(T entity);
  }
  ```
- `interface MyEntityDao`

  ```
  @Repository
  interface MyEntityDao extends AbstractDao<MyEntity, Integer> {
      public MyEntity get(String name);
  }
  ```

**Implementation under `myproject.data.dao.jpa`.**

- `abstract class AbstractDaoJpa`

  ```
  @Repository
  abstract class AbstractDaoJpa implements AbstractDao<T,K> {
      protected EntityManager em;
      @PersistenceContext
      public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
          em = entityManager;
      }

      public T save(T entity) {
          em.persist(entity);
          return entity;
      }

      public T update(T entity) {
          return em.merge(entity);
      }
  }
  ```
- `class MyEntityDaoJpa extends AbstractDaoJpa implements MyEntityDao`

  ```
  @Repository
  class MyEntityDaoJpa extends AbstractDaoJpa<MyEntity,Integer> implements MyEntityDao {
      @Override
      public MyEntity get(Integer key) {
          return em.find(MyEntity.class, key);
      }

      @Override
      public MyEntity get(String name) {
          return em.createQuery("select E from MyEntity E where E.name = :name", MyEntity.class).setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
      }

      ...
  }
  ```

---

#### Service layer:

**Interfaces under `myproject.data.service`**

- `interface EntityService`

  ```
  @Service
  public interface EntityService<T> extends Serializable {
      public Collection<T> getAll();
  }
  ```
- `interface MyEntityService extends EntityService`

  ```
  @Service
  public interface MyEntityService extends EntityService<MyEntity> {
      public MyEntity create(String name);
      public MyEntity get(String name);

      public MyEntity rename(String name);

      ...
  }
  ```

**Implementation under `myproject.data.service.impl`**

- `class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService`

  ```
  @Service
  public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {
      private MyEntityDao dao;

      public MyEntityServiceImpl(MyEntityDao newDao) {
          dao = newDao;
      }

      @Override
      public MyEntity create(String name) {
          MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
          e.name = name;
          ...
          return dao.save(e);
      }

      ...

      @Override
      public MyEntity rename(String oldName, String newName) {
          MyEntity e = dao.get(oldName);
          e.name = newName;
          dao.update(e); // An attempt to fix by explicitly merging the modified entity.
                         // Didn't fix the problem.
          return e;
      }

      ...
  }
  ```

---

#### Spring configuration:

```
...

[ Declaration of DAOs and Service beans. Appropriate DAOs are injected into Service beans. ]

...

<!-- Tomcat-managed DataSource lookup via JNDI -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDS"/>

<!-- Configure the EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Create the Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the Transaction Manager for AOP -->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- Some methods are read-only. -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS"/>
        <!-- All others, use defaults. -->
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

...

<!-- Configure Spring AOP -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="wholeProject" expression="within(myproject..*)"/>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceLayerOperation" expression="execution(* myproject.data.service.*.*(..))"/>

    <!-- Configure transaction management. -->
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" order="1" pointcut-ref="serviceLayerOperation"/>

    <!-- Configure logging interceptor. -->
    ...
</aop:config>
```

Comment: The logs indicate that the transaction starts before the method (*Exposing JPA transaction...*) and commits after (*Committing JPA transaction...*). What behavior do you observe, and what behavior do you expect? Moreover, your get method implementation takes an Integer, whereas the method of the interface takes a String.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the implementation of `public MyEntity get(String name);`

Comment: My guess is that you're renaming the entity with the same name as the one it already has. Why don't you show us the implementation of `public MyEntity get(String name);`?

Comment: [I don't know how I didn't see your comments since yesterday! I do apologize!]

`public MyEntity get(String name)` simply creates a JPA query to retrieve a persisted `MyEntity` by name.

Comment: I'm not simply assigning the same name as before.

I've traced through with Eclipse, and it looks like `MyEntityService.rename()` returns, after having renamed the appropriate `MyEntity` (from "nameA" to "name1", in my test case); *but* after the transaction has been committed, nothing has changed! (either in the PU or the DB)

Comment: Have you tried using getters and setters (as you should always do) rather than setting the fields directly?

Comment: Not yet. I'd read something a few weeks ago that argued against using getters/setters for *everything* in JPA. But perhaps EclipseLink isn't able to correctly create a proxy when using field access?

Comment: Some getters and setters are not necessary, or even desired. But replacing them with public fields is even worse. It breaks encapsulation even more that getters and setters for everything.

Comment: Fantastic! Replacing `public` access with getters/setters worked!

Thank you very much for your help, JB!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, to make it clear that the question has an answer, and help potential future readers. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you're accessing the fields of your entity directly, without going through getters/setters.

Using public fields is a very bad practice, because it breaks encapsulation. EclipseLink seems to need methods, probably becauseit's weaving consists in adding byte-code into the methods. By accessing the fields directly, you must bypass the bytecode additions that make EclipseLink work.